# jQuery Keypress Conflict

Tags: jquery, keypress, conflict

I've built a little app that pastes some user generated text in to a textarea via a drop in div. This is done with the .click function and the .keypress function (using the Enter key).

Is there a way to get the .keypress function to fire only when the div is displayed?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mobius1/Sjyeh/2/

---

**EDIT:**

**Now working!**

**Updated with Rory McCrossan's input: http://jsfiddle.net/Mobius1/Sjyeh/8/**

Comment: Good job for updating your question with the fact that you got your answer. To indicate which 'answer' answered your question, click the check mark next to it. Glad you found your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question, you can just check to see if the `.slidebox` div is visible in the `keypress()` handler:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && $(".slideBox").is(":visible")) {
        $("#dimBackgrnd").hide().fadeOut("slow");

        $("#slide").hide("drop", {
            direction: "down"
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sjyeh/4/)

Comment: You had a typo in the class name `slidebox`; his class was `slideBox`. Great solution, though!

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the element is visible in the event handler:

```
if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
    doMyAction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Visibility is the answer you're looking for. I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sjyeh/3/) to display a possibility. Here is the code:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if ($("#slide:visible").size() > 0) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {

            $("#dimBackgrnd").hide().fadeOut("slow");

            $("#slide").hide("drop", {
                direction: "down"
            }, 500);
        }
    }
});
```